# Which is correct: "of course" or "ofcourse"?

Tags: orthography, spacing

I have been using the term *, ofcourse,* ever since kindergarten.

However, I recently stumbled upon a site that claims *, of course,* is how the term is correctly used and not *ofcourse,*.

I would like to seek the community's opinion about which is the correct usage of that term.

Comment: Don'tbelieveallthosewhowanttoseparatewordswithspaces. YouandIareright,havealwaysbeen,andcanproveit. TheRomansusedtowritelikeus,andnobodyclaimstherewerewrong,dothey?

Comment: @FX_: Nice... :)

Comment: Can you point us to at least one of the "many novels"? I've never seen "ofcourse" in print.

Comment: You live in Germany, don't you?

Comment: It is not alright to use ofcourse ;)

Comment: @FX_ youmean"andnotbodyclaimstheywerewrong",right?

Comment: IfYouDontWantToPutSpacesBetweenYourWordsCouldYouAtLeast"TitleCase"ThemSoWeCanStillReadWithoutTooMuchTrouble?

Comment: I use ofcourse alot.

Comment: noone says ofcouse.

Comment: @zzzzBov: people may *say* ofcourse (how can you tell?) but noone *writes* it like that.

Comment: @Peter Shor, in case you missed it, `no one` is two words.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I'm not sure what novels you are referring to, but *ofcourse* is a typo. Wiktionary [doesn't have an entry](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ofcourse) for it, and neither does [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ofcourse) or [any dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/?w=ofcourse&ls=a) I have checked. Here are the usage stats from the [British National Corpus](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/) and the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://www.americancorpus.org/):

| expression | BNC | COCA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| of course | 29651 | 100939 |
| ofcourse | 1 | 12 |

Answer (score 41):

"Of course" is two words. I have never seen it as one except in typos and this question.

Comment: Technically speaking, this question has a typo :)

Comment: To be fair, the spelling was deliberate in the question and therefore not technically speaking a typo. ^_^

Answer (score 10):

Quoth the talking horse from a 1960s American sitcom:

> A horse is a horse, of course, of course, 
>   And no one can talk to a horse, of course.
>   That is, of course, unless the horse is the famous Mr. Ed.

I'd take it straight from the horse's mouth and write it thus: *of course*

Answer (score 5):

"Of course" is always 2 words, and is a shorter form of "As a matter of course". Furthermore, Google Fight says of course wins at 75 900 000 vs ofcourse which has only 521 000. If you Google it, half of the results on the first page are in the url, and the first result is another forum where this was asked.

Here are the Google Fight results: [Google Fight — *ofcourse* vs. *of course*](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=ofcourse&word2=of+course).

Comment: I'm not sure if *of course* and *as a matter of course* are synonyms in modern usage. The former might have evolved as a shortening of the latter, but somewhere along the way, they acquired a slight divergence in meaning.

Comment: @Marthaª I think though that that is as much that we just wouldn't use "as a matter of course" where we can use "of course" than anything else, so it would stand as a more emphatic statement than once it would. It's not far from how "if it please you" would stand as much stronger now that the contraction "please" is so much more common.

Answer (score -1):

I just checked Merriam-Webster dictionary and it has *ofcourse* defined as a 'matter of course', i.e. a natural flow of events.

Comment: [The Merriam-Webster I am checking right now](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ofcourse) does not have an entry for *ofcourse*. There is only one for "course (noun)" and one for "matter of course".